# Grouping by X days

Tags: mysql, group-by, statistics

I have a database that shows me different stats about different campaigns, each row has a timestamp value name "date".

I wrote the code for choosing and summarizing a range of dates, for example: 21-24/07/2010. 
Now I need to add an option to choose a range of dates, but also to group the stats for each X days.

Let's say the user chooses to see stats from all the month: 01/07-31/07. I would like to present him the stats grouped by X days, let's say 3, so he will see the stats 01-03/07, 04-06/07,07-09/07 and so on...

I almost managed doing it using this code:

```
SELECT t1.camp_id,from_days( floor( to_days( date ) /3 ) *3 ) AS 'first_date'
FROM facebook_stats t1
INNER JOIN facebook_to_campaigns t2 ON t1.camp_id = t2.facebook_camp_id
WHERE date
BETWEEN 20100717000000
AND 20100724235959
GROUP BY from_days( floor( to_days( date ) /3 ) *3 ) , t2.camp_id
```

It actually does group it (by 3 days), but the problem is that for some reason it starts from the 16/07, and not the 17/07, then grouping each time 3 days at a time.

Would love to hear a solution to the code or I gave, **or** a better solution you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

To_Days returns the number of days since the year 0. When you divide it by 3, it considers only the quotient and not the remainder. eg. If it has been 5 days since year 0, then to_days will return 1.

To_days(20100717000000) must be leaving a remainder of 1. Basically To_days(2010071**6**000000) is exactly divisible by 3 but 17th is not.

You could try this query:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime
DECLARE @groupByInterval INT
SET @startdate = 20100717000000
SET @enddate = 20100724235959
SET @groupByInterval = 3

SELECT 
t1.camp_id,   from_days(
to_days(@startDate)+floor(
(to_days(date)-to_days(@startDate))/@groupByInterval
)
* @groupByInterval) 
AS first_date
FROM facebook_stats t1
INNER JOIN facebook_to_campaigns t2 ON t1.camp_id = t2.facebook_camp_id
WHERE date
BETWEEN @startDate
AND @endDate
GROUP BY first_date , t2.camp_id
```

Comment: Edited to add a probable solution

Comment: P.S: I am primarily an MS SQL person, so the MySQL syntax might be wrong at places.

Comment: I don't know declare in mysql, can you please explain me abit about what it does? Is it like settings vars? I gave a specific example with dates, but they are dynamic, can I write the query so it changes by params I pass to it?

Comment: Yes, declare is like setting vars in standard SQL. I am not sure of the exact syntax in mysql. You can try googling it. 
And yes, you just need to change the value of @startDate and @endDate in the SET statements and it should work just like params. You can even change the interval.

Comment: Hey,
So the important thing is actually the first_date one:
from_days( to_days( 20100717000000 ) + floor( (
to_days( date ) - to_days( 20100717000000 ) ) /3 ) *3

Is that what you meant I should do?